# PHP, Reading PDF File Into String

Tags: php, pdf

I know this topic is too much discussed here, but I couldn't find what I want, I want to read a PDF file into a string in PHP, to search in it for a keyword for example.

I used to use 'XPDF' by using the 'pdftotext' command, it worked perfectly except that I have no success on a host other than the localhost because of disabling `shell_exec()` function on servers for security reasons.

I tried some other ways, there is a function for example called 'pdf2text' written on 'http://webcheatsheet.com' but it doesn't work, I keep getting an empty file.

So what I need is a way to read a PDF file to search in it, without getting any security error like the one for `shell_exec()`.